# JS for loop showing only last value (Not iterating whole values)

Tags: javascript

```
function addmsg(type, msg) {
    if (type = 'new') {
        $('#ntfcn').html(type);
        var notify = ["New Message", "New Mail", "New Event", "New Assignment"];
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < notify.length; i++) {
            $('#ntfcn_msg').html("<a href='employee-dashboard.jsp' id='' class='msg_show'><div class='media-body'><h6 class='media-heading'>" + notify[i] + "</h6></div></a>");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: What do you mean? What is the last value?

Comment: I've indented and formatted the code for you.

Comment: Last value in the array? `Use notify.length - 1`

Comment: Well, you overwrite the html every time you loop so....

Comment: use .append() instead .html()

Comment: This isn't your specific bug but this is definitely a typo: `type = 'new'`. You're assigning `'new'` to `type`. If you want to compare, do `type === 'new'`

Answer (score 1):

This line **overwrites** what's in the `ntfcn_msg` element on each loop iteration:

```
$('#ntfcn_msg').html("<a href='employee-dashboard.jsp' id='' class='msg_show'><div class='media-body'><h6 class='media-heading'>" + notify[i] + "</h6></div></a>");
```

you mean have meant to *append*:

```
$('#ntfcn_msg').append("<a href='employee-dashboard.jsp' id='' class='msg_show'><div class='media-body'><h6 class='media-heading'>" + notify[i] + "</h6></div></a>");
// -------------^
```

...perhaps with an `empty` in front of the loop to clear it out first:

```
$('#ntfcn_msg').empty();
```

So:

```
function addmsg(type, msg) {
    if (type == 'new') {
        $('#ntfcn').html(type);
        var notify = ["New Message", "New Mail", "New Event", "New Assignment"];
        var i;
        $('#ntfcn_msg').empty();
        for (i = 0; i < notify.length; i++) {
            $('#ntfcn_msg').append("<a href='employee-dashboard.jsp' id='' class='msg_show'><div class='media-body'><h6 class='media-heading'>" + notify[i] + "</h6></div></a>");
        }
    }
}
```

---

Another option is to use `Array#map`, `join`, and then `html`:

```
function addmsg(type, msg) {
    if (type == 'new') {
        $('#ntfcn').html(type);
        $('#ntfcn_msg').html(
            ["New Message", "New Mail", "New Event", "New Assignment"].map(function(text) {
                return "<a href='employee-dashboard.jsp' id='' class='msg_show'><div class='media-body'><h6 class='media-heading'>" + text + "</h6></div></a>";
            }).join("")
        );
    }
}
```

---

Side note: `id=''` doesn't do anything, you may as well just leave it off.

Side note 2: See [Mike C's point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43414637/js-for-loop-showing-only-last-value-not-iterating-whole-values/43414699#comment73888063_43414637) about

```
if (type = 'new') {
```

that should be

```
if (type == 'new') {
```

or

```
if (type === 'new') {
```

`=` is *assignment* (setting `type` to the value `'new'`). So you were setting `type` to `'new'`, then testing the result, and you'd always go into the body of the `if` because `'new'` is a truthy value.

Answer (score 0):

use .append() instead .html()

```
function addmsg(type, msg) {
        if (type = 'new') {
            $('#ntfcn').html(type);
            var notify = ["New Message", "New Mail", "New Event", "New Assignment"];
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < notify.length; i++) {
                $('#ntfcn_msg').append("<a href='employee-dashboard.jsp' id='' class='msg_show'><div class='media-body'><h6 class='media-heading'>" + notify[i] + "</h6></div></a>");
            }
        }
    }
```